Mocking useStorage() using @nuxt/test-utils
The goal is to write a test for a function that uses KV storage, under the hood provided by Nitro, in the Nuxt app. On the client side useStorage() is automatically imported. When writing a test, documentation recommends mocking the function.
After copying the snippet from the documentation as:
mockNuxtImport('useStorage', () => {
  return () => {
    return { value: 'mocked storage' }
  }
})

The test method fails with Error: Cannot find import "useStorage" to mock.
What should be imported to successfully mock the useStorage()?

The mock is not possible because useStorage is accessible only from a scope of Nitro which is at ~/server. Thus different approach must be used to test this method.

There is a difference between the built in from Nitro and the one from VueUse as shown in my link. Hence why the docs remind to import the good one.

Try to explicitly import it from VueUse
import { useStorage } from '@vueuse/core'

As told in this comment.

The issue still persists. Check this replication on StackBlitz as the same error occurs there as well: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-bf2fpu?file=test%2Futils.test.ts

@PozziUserpic you have not installed VueUse and I also do not see that error anywhere. Only ones are 'useStorage' is declared but its value is never read.(6133) and Cannot find module '@vueuse/core' or its corresponding type declarations.(2307).

My apologizes, the problem persists even when @vueuse/core is installed - as of now available on StackBlitz. The error is visible after running pnpm run test.

The function that uses useStorage is not using the one from @vueuse/core but the Nitro one. That's why adding direct import didn't help to solve the issue. Nitro one is not possible to mock, see my answer for more information.

I don't know if I am late but this was how I resolved the issue.
I used createStorage() from unstorage instead of using useStorage and setting up nitro in nuxt.config.ts.
import { createStorage } from 'unstorage';
import fs from 'unstorage/drivers/fs';

// Initialize the global storage
export const storage = createStorage({
    driver: fs({
        base: './.data/db',
    }),
});


In my server, I was able to import it and in my test, I was able to mock it.
// Mock the `storage` module
vi.mock('./storage', () => {
    return {
        storage: {
            getKeys: vi.fn().mockResolvedValue(['key1', 'key1']),
            getItem: vi.fn().mockImplementation((key) => {
                const data = {
                    'key1': { 'name': 'John Doe' },
                    'key2': { 'school': 'University of Toronto' }
                } as any;
                return Promise.resolve(data[key]);
            }),
            // Provide default implementations for all required methods
            hasItem: vi.fn().mockResolvedValue(true),
            getItems: vi.fn().mockResolvedValue([]),
            getItemRaw: vi.fn().mockResolvedValue(null),
            setItem: vi.fn().mockResolvedValue(undefined),
            removeItem: vi.fn().mockResolvedValue(undefined),
        }
    };
});


In your test file or beforeEach, you can use doMock.vi to modify as you may choose
